# Validate if there are no results returned from SQL query

Tags: php

below is my code. $data is the result of the query and i want the PHP to realise when there are no results returned and display the echo "There were no matching results..." if the DB does return a result, echo the table. the following doesn't realise when there are no results returned...

```
if ($data == null) {

        echo "<strong>There were no Matching Results...Please Return to the '<a href='section_search.php'>Section Search Page</a>'</strong></br></br></br>";

     }

     else {
      echo "<table border=0 cellpadding=10>";
    echo "<tr align = center bgcolor=white>
    <td><b>Company</b></td><td><b>Section</b></td><td><b>Question</b></td><td><b>Answer</b></td>" ; 
     while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
     { 
     echo "<tr>"; 
     echo "<td width = 60px><b>".boldText($info['company_name'], $kword) . "</b></td> ";
     echo "<td width = 60px><b>".boldText($info['section_name'], $kword) . "</b></td> "; 
     echo "<td width = 360px>".boldText($info['question'], $kword) . " </td>";
     echo "<td width = 600px>".boldText($info['answer'], $kword) . " </td></tr>"; 
     } 
     echo "</table>"; 
     }
    }
```

any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: how about using `mysqli_num_rows($data)`?

Comment: `if( mysql_num_rows( $data ) == 0 ) { //no results }`, but remember what mysql_* functions are deprecated, use PDO or mysqli instead of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows` to determine the number of results returned by your query. If it is `0` there are no results.

But in general you should stop using the old legacy `mysql_` methods. They are marked as [deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). You could use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Comment: Should be `mysqli_num_rows`, not `mysql_num_rows`, because of depreciation.

Comment: Since he himself is using `mysql_` and not `mysqli_` it might be more convenient to stick to `mysql`. In general you are right and I planned to update the answer as fast as possible to include links to the right resources in the manual.